# OSMNX graph from point and geometry information

Tags: python, networking, spatial, osmnx

I have been using osmnx for a while now, and doing:
G = ox.graph_from_point(city_center, distance=distance, network_type='drive', simplify=False)
was returning a graph

where an edge iteration
for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True)

would allow one to access the geographic coordinates of an edge in the following way:
data['geometry'].coords

in the latest effort, unfortunately the geometry property was not there. Any chance how one could access the coordinates of a node or an edge now?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example that we can copy/paste to run from scratch to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3):

OSMnx only adds a `geometry` attribute to simplified edges. If an edge is unsimplified, its geometry is a trivial straight line between its incident nodes `u` and `v`. In your code, you parameterized `graph_from_point` with `simplify=False`, hence none of your edges are simplified and none of them have `geometry` attributes:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

point = 40.729630, -73.998835
dist = 100
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=dist, network_type='drive', simplify=False) 

for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    simp = '' if 'geometry' in data else 'not '
    print(f'edge {data["osmid"]} has {simp}been simplified')
```

If you simplify the graph, some or all of its edges will have geometry attributes, depending on whether or not a particular street segment linking two intersections spanned multiple OSM nodes originally. The topological simplification methodology is detailed in [this paper](https://geoffboeing.com/publications/osmnx-complex-street-networks/). More details appear in [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/). Example:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

point = 40.729630, -73.998835
dist = 100
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=dist, network_type='drive', simplify=True) 

for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    simp = '' if 'geometry' in data else 'not '
    print(f'edge {data["osmid"]} has {simp}been simplified')
```

You can also manually add geometry attributes to each edge of a simplified or unsimplified graph by calling `graph_to_gdfs` with `fill_edge_geometry=True` then reconstructing your graph with `graph_from_gdfs`, like this:

```py
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

point = 40.729630, -73.998835
dist = 100
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=dist, network_type='drive', simplify=False)

# create nodes, edges GeoDataFrames and fill in all edge geometry attributes
# then re-create a MultiDiGraph from those GeoDataFrames
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, fill_edge_geometry=True)
G2 = ox.graph_from_gdfs(nodes, edges, graph_attrs=G.graph)

for u, v, data in G2.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    assert 'geometry' in data
```

Finally, in a comment above, you mentioned "I am using what is the latest version, which is osmnx 0.16.1." But, your code snippet can't be using v0.16.1 because the `distance` parameter was deprecated and eventually replaced with `dist` 5 or 6 versions ago. Try running `print(ox.__version__)` to see what version you're actually using.

Comment: Thanks for this! I think I really really need to meditate on the simplification concept as I recall it got me confused during a previous interaction on the same parameter https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/427 ....

Comment: just added a cross-reference to this answer on that github issue

Comment: Referring to your comment above 'OSMnx only adds a geometry attribute to simplified edges. If an edge is unsimplified, its geometry is a trivial straight line between its incident nodes u and v.' , I was wondering. If the case is, then I should be able to get at least the node coordinates. Obtaining a graph using G = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=dist, network_type='drive', simplify=False), and then iterating through nodes(), I see no lat/lng or geometry attributes involved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet but now even upon data retrieval I get

the following errors:
File ../python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/core.py", line 931, in create_graph
raise EmptyOverpassResponse('There are no data elements in the response JSON objects')
osmnx.errors.EmptyOverpassResponse: There are no data elements in the response JSON objects

```
import osmnx as ox
import sys

newyork_center = (40.729630, -73.998835)
distance = 100.0  

G = ox.graph_from_point(newyork_center, distance=distance, network_type='drive', simplify=False) 

for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    try:
        print (data)
        print (data['geometry'].coords)
    except:
        print (sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: What version of OSMnx are you using? Regardless of the version, note that the distance argument you're providing always is in units of meters. See [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_point). the error message is just telling you that there are no street network data within 1 meter of that point, as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the code snippet now to first have a better input argument for distance. I have also corrected an error that was "inherited" accidentally as I was extracting the code snippet from a larger codebase. The output of an iteration of the above for loop is: {'osmid': 5672138, 'name': 'Laguardia Place', 'highway': 'residential', 'maxspeed': '25 mph', 'oneway': False, 'length': 79.494}
(<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('geometry'), <traceback object at 0x1a273d0c30>) --- To answer your first question, I am using what is the latest version, which is osmnx 0.16.1.

Comment: Your code snippet isn't using v0.16.1 because the `distance` parameter was deprecated and eventually replaced with `dist` 5 or 6 versions ago. Try running `print(ox.__version__)` to see what version you're actually using.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. You are right, the python environment I am actually running this uses osmnx version 0.12. I think I got a few of those installed at different environments and hence the confusion :(